# KeyError: 'name' Why can't I use 'name'?

Tags: python, django

I wanna make a dictionary has name's key & data.In views.py I wrote

```
data_dict ={}
def try_to_int(arg):
    try:
        return int(arg)
    except:
        return arg

def main():
    book4 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
    sheet4 = book4.sheet_by_index(0)

    data_dict_origin = OrderedDict()
    tag_list = sheet4.row_values(0)[1:]
    for row_index in range(1, sheet4.nrows):
        row = sheet4.row_values(row_index)[1:]
        row = list(map(try_to_int, row))
        data_dict_origin[row_index] = dict(zip(tag_list, row))

    if data_dict_origin['name'] in data_dict:
        data_dict[data_dict_origin['name']].update(data_dict_origin)
    else:
        data_dict[data_dict_origin['name']] = data_dict_origin

main()
```

When I printed out `data_dict`,it is

```
OrderedDict([(1, {'user_id': '100', 'group': 'A', 'name': 'Tom', 'dormitory': 'C'}), (2, {'user_id': '50', 'group': 'B', 'name': 'Blear', 'dormitory': 'E'})])
```

My ideal dictionary is

```
dicts = {
    Tom: {
        'user_id': '100',
        'group': 'A', 
        'name': 'Tom',
        'dormitory': 'C'
    },
    Blear: {
    },
}
```

How should I fix this?What should I write it?

Comment: why first time you use `Tom` and next `2` ?

Comment: @BearBrown Sorry,it is mistaken.I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The code is using the wrong key in the dictionary. The keys are 1, 2, and do not have the `name` key. You can use this code instead:

```
for value in data_dict.values():
    if value['name'] in data_dict:
        data_dict[value['name']].update(value)
    else:
        data_dict[value['name']] = value
```

Comment: thx,ur answer.i wrote ur codes,but {} was printed out.I think  maybe data_dict.values() is data_dict_origin.values() .How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `data_dict_origin` has numbers as keys and dicts as values (which technically makes it a sparse array of dicts). The "name" key exists in those dicts, not in your `data_dict`.

Comment: @user8504021 please avoid the childish spelling, it's not hoing to make you look smart here. And SO is not a free gimme-da-code-plz service either FWIW.